# Filter Array of Arrays in JavaScript to become unique

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

This is how I would filter an array of numbers to become unique:

```
const unique = (value, index, self) => {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index
}

const costs = [10, 8, 5, 5, 8, 7]
const uniqueCosts = costs.filter(unique)

console.log(uniqueCosts) // [10,8,5,7]
```

How could I filter an array of arrays to be unique:
`arr = [[10,10],[8,8],[5,5],[5,5],[8,8],[7,7]]`
`-> uniqueArr =[[10,10],[8,8],[5,5],[7,7]]`

I have looked into creating a new [Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which again works quite well in a simple array however the `.add` function of a set seems to add an array to the set even if the array is already in the set.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm looking for a simple solution, using the power of existing functions in JavaScript without involving `for/while` loops.

Many thanks!

Comment: you can use .flat to flatten it and then use the same

Comment: Depends on what kind of uniqueness you want. Please show the expected output. I assume you're checking array equality, yes?

Comment: What is the expected result for `arr = [[10,10],[8,8],[5,5],[5,5],[8,8],[7,7]]`?

Comment: @ggorlen, @hev1 this is the expected result `uniqueArr =[[10,10],[8,8],[5,5],[7,7]]`

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi thank you, but I want to keep the structure of the embedded arrays however flat would lose that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a `Set` with a serializing function for getting strings without different object references.

```js
const
    serialize = v => JSON.stringify(v),
    unique = array => array.filter((s => v => (t => !s.has(t) && s.add(t))(serialize(v)))(new Set));

console.log(unique([10, 8, 5, 5, 8, 7]));
console.log(unique([[10, 10], [8, 8], [5, 5], [5, 5], [8, 8], [7, 7]]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```